# How to print the total in RISC-V Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, riscv

This code is supposed to store the numbers in an array, and then print the total of positive numbers, and total of negative numbers. I am not sure what I am doing wrong!
It prints out the messages without the total. I am using RISC-V assembly language in RARS simulator

This is my current outcome:

```
Positive Integers Total: 
Negative Integers Total: 
Negative Integers Total: 
-- program is finished running (0) --
```

Does not display the total values. How can I fix it?

```
#----Calculate the Sum of Positive and Negative Numbers In An Array----#
########################################################################
    .data
array:      .word 22,-35,48,10,-15,-30,25,20,-1,-26,-18,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,-9,1,-4,-3,-2,1,6,0 #array input
positiveSum:    .word 0
negativeSum:    .word 0

#outcome messages
position:       .word 0 #index posisiont of array
length:     .word 9
posTotal:       .ascii "\nPositive Integers Total: "
negTotal:       .ascii "\nNegative Integers Total: "

    .text
main:
       
       la t0,array      #load array to register t0 
       lw t1,position
       lw s1, positiveSum   #load the positive sum to s1, and negative sum to s2
       lw s2,negativeSum

loop:
           #calculate the index position in terms of memory
           #each integer needs 4 bytes
           #so shift left the value in t1 and store it in t3
    slli t3,t1,2
        add t3,t3,t0        #add the base address and the above result
        lw t4,0(t3)     #load the word from above address into t4
        beqz t4,exit        #exit loop when reaching 0
        j checkSign     #if value is not 0 jump to check integer sign

checkSign:
               
        bltz t4,addNegative     #check if array value is negative 
    j addPositive       # if yes goto addnegative
                        #if not goto addpositive
               
addPositive:
        add s1,s1,t4        #add all positive integers to s1 register
        j increment     #increment
               
addNegative:
        add s2,s2,t4        #add the negative integers to the s2 register
        j increment     #increment
           
increment:
        addi t1,t1,1        #increment the current index in t1 by 1
        j loop
          
exit:               #end of program
        la a0,posTotal   
        li a7,4         #print the positive sum 
        ecall
        
        la a0,negTotal
        li a7,4     #print the negative sum 
        ecall

    ori a7, zero, 10    #program exit system call
    ecall           # exit program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing only posTotal and negTotal. You need to print also positiveSum and negativeSum after converting them to ascii format.

I don't known how your ecall works , but you need to add two calls to ecall when you put the ascii from of your Sums in a0 (this solution will always work), or if the ecall can take more than one argument place the Sum as the second argument by using a1.

You got `Negative Integers Total:` printed twice because you did not add `\0` at the end of your strings, so the first time you print the first string but continue printing until you found an \0.

I recommend you add an alignment directive between your strings like `.balign 4`.

```
posTotal:       .ascii "\nPositive Integers Total: \0"
.balign 4
negTotal:       .ascii "\nNegative Integers Total: \0"
```

the `j checkSign` and the second `j increment` are useless.

Comment: You can use `.asciiz` instead of a manual `\0` in `.ascii`.  You don't generally need alignment for strings, although I guess alignment by 4 might possibly make the kernel's strcpy or strlen faster if it checks for alignment to start with.